# [Solved] publisher problem in hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I have a really strange behaviour I can not explain. I have a really simple program where I publish a message and then quit. When im not sleeping after creating the publisher, but i start immediately to publish the messages gets lost. Any ideas what the case may be?
I am using hydro, and the roscore runs locally.

thanks
flavio

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "publish_test");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher set_control_active_pub = nh.advertise< std_msgs::Float32>("/pixhawk_bridge/control_active2",10 );


  ros::Duration(2).sleep();


  std_msgs::Float32 activate_msg;
  activate_msg.data = 0;
  set_control_active_pub.publish( activate_msg );
  ros::spinOnce();
  ros::Duration(2).sleep();




  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110056/%5Bsolved%5D-publisher-problem-in-hydro/) by [ffontana](https://answers.ros.org/users/7296/ffontana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In essence it is likely that the message gets published before any subscribers have the chance to establish a connection to the publisher. It takes some time. There are some ways to check if and how many subscribers are connected to your publisher. For a detailed answer see this question & answer:

http://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message/

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess it could be because you publish the message only once.
try to put set_control_active_pub.publish( activate_msg ); into a while, something like:

```
  std_msgs::Float32 activate_msg;
  while(ros::ok()){
    activate_msg.data = 0;
    set_control_active_pub.publish( activate_msg );
    ros::spinOnce();
    ros::Duration(2).sleep();
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1